# Marshalling data for C#

Tags: c#, c++

I have not many experience in such language as C# so I would be pleased if you guys could help me. I wrote this method in C++ using MPIR library:

```
mpz_class SchnorrProtocol::getX(const mpz_class& r) const
{
    mpz_class x;
    mpz_powm(x.get_mpz_t(), this->params_.getBeta().get_mpz_t(), r.get_mpz_t(), this->params_.getP().get_mpz_t());
    return x;
}
```

and now I want to import it to C#:

```
  #region Filter & P/Invoke
#if DEBUG
        private const string DLL = "schnorrd.DLL";
#else
       private const string DLL = "schnorr.DLL";
#endif

        [DllImport(DLL)]
  "method definition"
        ......  SchnorrProtocol::getX(......);
```

my problem, I don't know how to do it. Could u please help me?

Answer (score 1):

You have to use [structlayout attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.structlayoutattribute.aspx) to define mpz_class, i.e.,

```
  [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit, Size=16, CharSet=CharSet.Ansi)]
   public class mpz_class 
   {
      // your class definition
   }

  [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit, Size=16, CharSet=CharSet.Ansi)]
   public class SchnorrProtocol 
   {
           // your class definition.
   }
```

And [here's how](http://blogs.msdn.com/sanpil/archive/2004/07/07/175855.aspx) you marshal a method inside a C++ class

```
[ DllImport( DLL, 
    EntryPoint="?getX@SchnorrProtocol@@QAEHH@Z", 
    CallingConvention=CallingConvention.ThisCall )]
    public static extern int TestThisCalling( SchnorrProtocol prot );
```

Comment: the problem is:
mpz_class is C++ class which is avalable with:

#include <mpirxx.h>

so the standard operators and various standard functions are overloaded to allow arithmetic with this class.

I don't know how to write a definition of such class.:(